# Different result during uint to uchar conversion on CPU and GPU on OpenCL

Tags: opencl

Here is the sample what is going on:

```
__kernel void test( __global uint* input, __global uchar* output)
{
    uint t[10];
    t[0] = 63782405;

    uint t1[10];
    doSomeCalculations(t1);
    doSomeOtherStuff(t1);//after calculations t1[0] is also 63782405;

    output[0] = uchar(t[0]);
    output[1] = uchar(t1[0]);
}
```

On my host I see that output[0] is 5, but output[1] is 102 when I run it on GPU. When I run it on CPU then output[0] is 5, and output[1] is 5. So it works correct on CPU and wrong on GPU.
Also, if I declare output as uint, then output[0] and output[1] is 5 on CPU and GPU as well.
Any ideas, how it can be?

Updated: 
To be more clear,
When:

```
__kernel void test( __global uint* input, __global uint* output)
    {
        uint t[10];
        t[0] = 63782405;

        uint t1[10];
        doSomeCalculations(t1);
        doSomeOtherStuff(t1);//after calculations t1[0] is also 63782405;

        output[0] = t[0];
        output[1] = t1[0];
    }
```

output[0] is 63782405,
output[1] is 63782405

When:

```
__kernel void test( __global uint* input, __global uint* output)
    {
        uint t[10];
        t[0] = 63782405;

        uint t1[10];
        doSomeCalculations(t1);
        doSomeOtherStuff(t1);//after calculations t1[0] is also 63782405;

        output[0] = uchar(t[0]);
        output[1] = uchar(t1[0]);
    }
```

output[0] is 5,
output[1] is 5

And When:

```
__kernel void test( __global uint* input, __global uchar* output)
    {
        uint t[10];
        t[0] = 63782405;

        uint t1[10];
        doSomeCalculations(t1);
        doSomeOtherStuff(t1);//after calculations t1[0] is also 63782405;

        output[0] = uchar(t[0]);
        output[1] = uchar(t1[0]);
    }
```

output[0] is 5,
output[1] is 102

Comment: Sure, it can be that t1[0] was overflowed somewhere, but for me it's strange that  it affects in this way. I also tried to do & 0xFF to get only first 8bits, result is the same - 102 instead of 5. Looks like GPU keeps in memory overflowings somehow and the uses them for next calculations... I'm newbie in OpenCL and for me this behaviour is strange

Comment: `output[0] =` and `output[1] =` are both data write race conditions. Because all workitems run this same kernel.

Comment: No, there is no race conditions. I made it just for example with 1 work item queued to show problem, that when I use output as array of uchar I have different result on CPU and GPU, when it is uint then result is the same and correct.

Comment: How about adding `barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE | CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);` after `doSomeOtherStuff(t1);...`? Does that affect the result?

Comment: Didn't help. Heh, I can't provide all sources, because it's about 1k lines of calculations. So, probably I will use uint for output array. But still curious :)

Comment: Very likely the problem is in either `doSomeCalculations` or `doSomeOtherStuff`. You could try to remove some parts there step by step and compare the results between CPU and GPU to narrow down the problem. Or from another end - assigning `t1[0] = 63782405;` and commenting out both function calls - which should return consistent results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is such a thing as `uchar(value)` in OpenCL, and if any compiler supports it, it's likely unofficial.

First, conversions between scalars are implicit (so you actually don't need anything, just a simple assignment `output[0] = t[0]`). Implicit conversions for vectors are forbidden.

Second, the official **explicit** way to convert both scalars and vectors is `convert_type{,_sat,_round_mode}(value)`, so for your case it's `output[0] = convert_uchar(t[0])`. The official way to *cast* a value (reinterpret bits) is `as_type()` (just FYI).

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this way of casting also doesn't work properly. Result on CPU is correct, but GPU is wrong. Also I'v realized that some other calculations have wrong results on my GPU. Probably because I run it trough golang, or because something wrong with my macbook (late 2011) + Sierra.